# Unordered bulk update in MongoDB using JAVA

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have  MongoDB documents like:

`{_id:1001, "title":"abc", "author":"xyz"}`

What is the best way to update author for 1 million such documents? I came to know about the *unordered bulk update* in MongoDB. How to implement that using Mongo's Java Driver.

Comment: The bulk operations are used to buffer write operations it client side and execute these in batches. In order to achieve what you want, issue an update comment `db.books.update({auther : "xyz"},{$set : {author: "whatever"}}, {multi:true})`

Comment: don't you think a bulk operation is faster in this case?

Comment: Well, I don't see any added value if merely want to update a single field for a bunch of documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = (DB) mongo.getDB("test1");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    BulkWriteOperation builder = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    builder.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1001)).upsert()
                    .replaceOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1001).append("author", "newName"));
    //append all other documents 
    builder.execute();
```

Comment: @Orid This is what I am talking about.

Comment: But this replaces the entire document and doesn't update it. After this operation the field 'title' id removed from the document.